# HPCCSystems - ECL, Does NOTHOR runs on hthor or one node of thor?

Tags: hpcc-ecl, hpcc

Using ECL/HPCC, I'm working with a team on an issue. They're trying to run actions within child queries.  During trying different solution a question came up:

Does ECL code executing with a NOTHOR actually execute within hthor, or on one node inside of thor?  Or does it matter based on what is executing?

Answer (score 1):

NOTHOR() indicates that you need that portion of the code to run on the single-node hThor "cluster" -- usually because you're doing something that doesn't need/want massively parallel execution (such as using a Standard Library function to spray a file from the Landing Zone to your Thor cluster)

Comment: Thank you, so can it execute  on one node inside of Thor? Or only hThor?

Comment: hThor is like a 1-node Thor. Thor jobs always execute on all nodes, so you cannot limit it to just one. NOTHOR() makes that part of the code run on hThor instead of the Thor.